# Reading decimals in text file into a 1D array

Tags: text-processing, array

So I have this text file named sortedtime.txt containing sorted decimals and integers listed line by line:

```
  12.6
  13.7
  ...
  154
  1864
```

I need a shell script that will read these numbers and add them into a 1D array line by line. The code I have for this is below:

```
 with open('sortedtime.txt') as data:
      timearray = data.readlines()
```

Unfortunately I keep getting an error when trying to execute the code. I need to be able to have these numbers as elemeents in an array to later plot a cdf of the data.

Comment: Do you want a shell script or a python script? You are showing python code, how are you executing it? Also, when asking questions, *never* say "I get an error", that isn't really useful. We need to see the exact error message in order to be able to help.

Comment: This belongs on SO.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you mean a *shell array*, note that not all shells support arrays. If we limit to Bourne like shells, the ones that support arrays (in chronological order) are `ksh`, `bash`, `zsh` and `yash`. `python` (the code you gave looks like `python` code) is not what we generally call a shell.

Of those, the only shells that support floating point arithmetics are `ksh93`, `zsh` and `yash`.

In all 3, and assuming the input contains only those floating point numbers separated by newline, space or tab, you can do:

```
array=($(cat file))
```

The syntax for accessing array elements is different in all 3 though. See "[Test for array support by shell](/q/238080)" for differences in array support in various shells.